# How do I make a Simple Python Encrypter

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

Code:

```
a=26
b=25
c=24
d=23
e=22
f=21
g=20
h=19
i=18
j=17
k=16
l=15
m=14
n=13
o=12
p=11
q=10
r=9
s=8
t=7
u=6
v=5
w=4
x=3
y=2
z=1
print ("Please print string:")
str1 = str(raw_input(">"))
print str1
```

But how do I make it convert `str1` into the integers above? And I'm very much a newbie by the way.

Answer (score 2):

One liner because I was bored:

```
print ''.join([str(123-ord(l))for l in str(raw_input("Print String:\n>"))])
```

However this is probably more what you were wanting:

```
print ("Please print string:")
str1 = str(raw_input(">"))

offset = 1
values = [ord(l) + offset for l in str1]

print ''.join([chr(v) for v in values])
```

This makes a list of ascii values for each letter in the string offset by your encryption constant, then converts them back to characters (now offset) and joins the list into a string.

Or in function form:

```
print ("Please print string:")
str1 = str(raw_input(">"))

def encrypt(string,offset):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(l) + offset) for l in string])

print encrypt(str1,2)
```

You can then call encrypt on any string and offset it by your desired value. Call encrypt with your offset value negated (1 goes to -1, etc.) to unencrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I could not do this using the builtin `string.translate`, but the following 2 work fine.

```
import string
# Construct a dictionary for required translation
translation = {}
for index, char in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
    translation[char] = 26 - index

# Function to translate given string
def translate(user_string):
    return "".join([str(translation[c]) for c in user_string])

user_string = raw_input("Enter your string - ")
print translate(user_string)
```

Note - The `string.ascii_lowercase` gives `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

If you don't want to convert the translated to a string, you can do

```
from __future__ import print_function
import string

translation = {}
for index, char in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
    translation[char] = 26 - index

user_string = raw_input("Enter your string - ")
for c in user_string:
    print(translation[c],end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Question has already been answered, but in general if you were looking to still use the code you had written you would want to use a dictionary:

```
letters = {"a": 26, "b": 25...}
return ''.join([letters[item] for item in str(raw_input("Print String:\n>"))])
```